# How to add points row to users?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, points

I'm trying to add a points row to to a table of current users on my website but I keep getting the error `#1062 - Duplicate entry '10' for key 'PRIMARY'`  when I try to set the default points to 10 for all users. I see this being a problem when both users end up reaching a same score of 150 etc.  Here are the settings for my table

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my query

```
<?php

session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "db_name");

$username = $_SESSION['username']; 

mysqli_query($db, 'UPDATE login_users SET Points=Points+1 WHERE username=$username');


?>
```

Any ideas to allow the same numbers to be stored in the points row? It seems that it is treating it as an "ID" instead of just a number.  Thanks!

Comment: Edited and added it at the bottom of the description, thank you!

Comment: I couldn't see anything wrong with this query except `"UPDATE login_users SET Points=Points+1 WHERE username='$username'"` - quote on username. Is there other place you are executing another query?

Comment: If you're using `mysqli`, which is a great thing, *always* make use of the available [SQL escaping methods](http://bobby-tables.com/php). That should be `WHERE username=?` with a subsequent call to `bind_param`. What you have there is **extremely** dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a `UNIQUE` index on the `Points` column, so you should probably drop it since that doesn't make any sense.

You might want paste the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE login_users` rather than a screenshot of the database editor you use.